# In Visual Studio 2022, as soon as I move my mouse and hover over other item it changes immediately. ¿How can I fix this?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, user-interface, menu, tweak

As soon as I hover on a menu item, the menu reacts and changes to the next **immediately**. That makes navigating between menus items extremely difficult because the lack of the 200/300ms typical delay.

Is there a setting to change this almost unusable behavior? Is it something from the OS (Windows 10) or something from the IDE?

Comment: What do you mean by "the next"? Does it not select the one where your mouse pointer is?

Comment: Thanks for your question. What I've meant is, yeah everything behaves as it should except that if your mouse pointer moves just a few pixels out of the menu element, it immediately selects other. 
There's is not a delay, we're all used for a delay,  ~1/3 of a second. I am force to not miss a pixel, which makes my IDE unusable, Hope this helps.

Comment: I've found out that it was a general Windows 10 setting that I needed to change in he registry, I've set it back to 300ms and I can work again, thanks.

Comment: You may want to add your own answer with the details so that others with the same question can find the answer.

Comment: I agree, it is really, really bad, and there is no setting for any delay or to even disable it. The settings for Intellisense inline hints also do nothing.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is on a Windows Registry key. The issue was caused by a Windows 10 setting set to 0 (0ms).

This is the path to the registry key:
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop**

You should find a **MenuShowDelay** there, change the value to **300** or maybe 400

Also, could try to find your own most comfortable value by trying different settings, just don't move too far away from 300ms.

Comment: This setting has no effect on VS2022. Tooltips show immediately and it is horribly annoying. It makes working with this IDE frustrating to impossible. You move the mouse to select something -> tooltip -> you move the mouse somewhere else, but the tooltip won't go away. It's beyond me.